# Xcode 5 not reading from standard input without debugger

Tags: xcode, xcode5

When trying to run a C++ command-line application from Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008) with no debugger, I am unable to get input from stdin to reach my app in the Debug area.

This doesn't work with even the most simple application like the one below. The application below will just wait for input to arrive until I kill the application manually.

Running it from the terminal, outside of Xcode, works just fine, and modifying the project scheme to cause the program to run under lldb gets everything to work correctly.

How do I get it to work as expected with no debugger?

Program:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("press enter to continue\n");
    getchar();
    // when run with no debugger from xcode 5.1.1, I am unable to get the following
    // line of code to execute.
    printf("enter pressed!\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `debug executable` option must be enabled to being able to type `stdin`.

In my case, I don't care if the debugger is enabled as long as it runs `fast`(Damn! It's takes about **5-10 seconds** to run a simple `type your name` c++ program).

Finally I found the solution: **disable** `Enable user interface debugging`

[image]